# [PHP/JavaScript]: Get PHP session value in other file's JavaScript function

Tags: php, javascript

I have a PHP file and it holds a value in this session variable: $_SESSION['image_value'].

I want this session value in a JavaScript function. Actually, I want to match a string in my JavaScript function with this session value.

Anyway I can do this?

Comment: What do you mean with "other file"? Is there a separation between PHP and JS files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use json_encode():

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var image_value = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['image_value'], JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>;
</script>
```

But be aware that PHP is entirely server-side and javascript is entirely client-side. That variable will be set when the page loads and any javascript modifications to it will not be preserved in the session.

Answer (score 1):

In your javascript code, instantiate x like this:

```
var x = "<?=$_SESSION['image_value']?>";
```

then just use it to do your comparisons or whatever. Of course, the script has to be evaluated by the server first, so putting this inside a .js file will not work. You need to put this in the .php file, in a  tag. Maybe to this then call a function in a js file if you need to.